# how to use writeUTF() method the right way?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, dataoutputstream

I am trying to make simple client and server that exchanges files, so, I am trying to use the `writeUtf()` method to send the file name as a `String`, but it is not working at all.

```
 public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 1241);
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
String currentPath = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream dataInFromServer = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
Scanner keyboardInput=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Operation Type(PUt, Get, Or Exit)");
String OperationType=keyboardInput.nextLine();
switch(OperationType){
case "PUT":
    outToServer.writeChar('P');
    System.out.println("File Or Directory name:");
    String FileOrDirName=keyboardInput.nextLine();
    //outToServer.writeUTF(FileOrDirName);
    //outToServer.write((short)FileOrDirName.length());
        outToServer.writeUTF(FileOrDirName);
    File fileOrDir=new File(FileOrDirName);
    if(fileOrDir.getParent()==currentPath || fileOrDir.getParent()==null){
    if(fileOrDir.isDirectory()){
        outToServer.writeInt(1);
        FileOperations.zipDir(fileOrDir);
        outToServer.write(FileOperations.readFileAsByteArray(FileOrDirName+".zip"));

        File tmp=new File(FileOrDirName+".zip");
        tmp.delete();
    }
    else {
        outToServer.writeInt(0);

        byte toSend[]=FileOperations.readFileAsByteArray(FileOrDirName);
        outToServer.writeDouble(toSend.length);
        for(int i=0; i<toSend.length; i++)
                outToServer.writeByte(toSend[i]);
    //  outToServer.write(ToSend,0,ToSend.length);
        //outToServer.write(FileOperations.readFileAsByteArray(FileOrDirName));
}
    outToServer.flush();
    outToServer.close();
    keyboardInput.close();
    client.close();
}   
    }

}
    }
```

and here is the Server:

```
        import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

class TcpFileServerThread extends Thread{
    private Socket client;
    public TcpFileServerThread(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dataInFromClient = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream()) ;
            Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
            String currentPath = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
            //File f;
            //System.out.println(dataInFromClient.readInt());
            /** client request PUT **/
            switch(dataInFromClient.readChar()){
            case 'P':
            int lengthRecvd= (int)dataInFromClient.readDouble();
            byte[] toRecv=new byte[lengthRecvd];

            for(int i=0; i<lengthRecvd; i++){
                toRecv[i]=dataInFromClient.readByte();
            }

        //  dataInFromClient.read(file_or_dir_from_client);
            //FileOrDirName="uu.txt";
            String FileOrDirName=dataInFromClient.readUTF();
        //  int arrLen=dataInFromClient.readShort();
        /** for(int i=0; i<arrLen; i++){
                char o=dataInFromClient.readChar();
                System.out.println(o);
            }**/

            System.out.println(FileOrDirName);
            File f=new File(FileOrDirName);
            if(f.getParent()==null || f.getParent()==currentPath){

            FileOperations.writeFromByteArrayToFile(toRecv, FileOrDirName); 
            if(dataInFromClient.readInt()==1){
                File zipFl=new File(FileOrDirName+".zip");
            FileOperations.unzip(zipFl);
                zipFl.delete();
            }   
            }

            }



        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

I get `FileNotFoundException` and the output for `System.out.println(FileOrDirName)` in server is a blank line as it was empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one way to use it, and this isn't it.

```
int lengthRecvd= (int)dataInFromClient.readDouble();
```

Here you are reading a `double` that hasn't been written. So you will get whatever the double value of the next 8 bytes in the input is.

```
        byte[] toRecv=new byte[lengthRecvd];
        for(int i=0; i<lengthRecvd; i++){
            toRecv[i]=dataInFromClient.readByte();
        }
```

Here you are reading that many bytes of input, which could be anything, and which also hasn't been written.

Remove all this.

```
        String FileOrDirName=dataInFromClient.readUTF();
```

Here you are finally reading the data, which is the only thing that has actually been written.

It is surprising that this code doesn't throw an `IOException` of some kind.

You can only read with `DataInputStream` data that has actually been written by the corresponding method of `DataOutputStream`, apart from mere byte arrays.